# Started with "Not secure" warning, then when logging into admin stuck on "my account" page to reset password, can't make any further actions

Tags: admin, customer-account, ssl, https, secure

My magento page which was **recently secure**, has given me a **warning through chrome** that it is not secure. In an attempt to check on the status of my account info to see if there was anything I could do in the **back end**, I got stuck on the **"It's time to change your password"** page in my account settings; I tried to change it, but nothing happens, and then clicking elsewhere just brings me back to the **"change your password"** screen. Is there a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the SSL certificate on your server has expired meaning you can't access secure pages (like the admin panel).
You may need to contact your server provider to install a new certificate.